# Insert into temporary table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, insert, temp-tables

```
select t.* 
into #temp 
from 
( 
select 'a' as a 
union all 
select 'b' as a 
) as t 

select * from #temp 

drop table #temp
```

i usually do this on SQL server wherein i create a temporary table. 
the syntax "into #temp" creates a non-physical table on the DB, while "into temp" will create a physical table on the DB.

My problem in MySQL is to convert the above MSSQL statement. What i want is to create is a temporary table that is not physically created on the DB. Do we have this feature in MySQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MySQL, you would use `create temporary table as`:

```
create temporary table temp as
    select 'a' as a 
    union all 
    select 'b' as a ;
```

Comment: It's scope is to session only?

Comment: And MySQL also has `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE table` to drop the temp table.

Comment: "You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. A TEMPORARY table is visible only within the current session, and is dropped automatically when the session is closed. This means that two different sessions can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of the same name. " @RamSingh source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html